# AUTOSAR Acceptance Test

Tags: autosar

once again, I'm here to ask about common AUTOSAR phrases and terms.
Since I'm not that familiar with the phrases/procedures, I want to ask it here.

In a test step, it says:

> In the SWC, Wait at read wait point for incoming data.

What does this mean? I've already read a bunch of confusing statements in the SWS, but I still can't decipher how the procedure should be done.

In the same test scenario but different test step, it says:

> Receive data at read wait point and store it in "rx"

Here, I understand that I will store the received data in a variable called "rx" but I do not understand, the receiving part.

Could someone please help me? AUTOSAR Q&A is so scarce! :(

Comment: I recommend to quote (or at least refer to) the "confusing statements" you mentioned. Not critizising you, I so agree that AUTOSAR texts are hard to read. But as generically as you describe, you suffer the risk that answers will just quote exactly those things you already found yourself. You might also want to make the role more clear which the acceptance test plays in your question, because (maybe only for me) it is not clear how your understandable question about the read wait point concept hinges on the scope of an acceptance test.

Comment: Hi, these phrases are excerpt from Diagnostic Services ATS. Those phrases are the phrases themselves, I've added or subtracted nothing from it. Apologies since I'm not an AUTOSAR developer. I'm only tasked to create acceptance tests. Sorry.

Comment: mmm, do you know what a "wait point" is? or the problem is something else?

Comment: i dont know but i think it is a callback when an event is received, and i believe it is blocking, right?